# How to compile/migrate a Visual Studio solution from a machine to another?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

Recently I obtained a solution which has been created on another person's machine. I have been banging my head into the monitor in the past 2 days trying to fully migrate the solution to my machine. I have been manually changing the directory addresses of the solution and have not been able to compile the solution although I think I have corrected more than 100 paths as of now. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35950588/cannot-compile-a-visual-studio-project-created-on-a-different-machine-computer)'s my first attempts to migrate the solution to my machine and resolve the issue of not being able to open any of the files.

Now I can open all the files in each project on my machine (after manually changing their paths). However, I am still getting the same errors and I'm not able to compile the project. Below is a picture of the errors I'm getting:

[image]

And [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0t47h9fsff9nty/Logs.txt?dl=0)'s the output log when trying to compile the project. So I wonder, can someone give me some advise on how I should go about doing the whole process automatically? In the [output log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0t47h9fsff9nty/Logs.txt?dl=0) I see there is a F:\Virtual ... path which indicates the solution been created on a virtual machine. However, I am not using a virtual machine and am not able to find the file file containing that path (F:...) so that I can change it to the correct one (I even do not know what the correct one should be since I am not using a VM).

If you are not able to help me through the description I gave or the output log file, you can download the whole solution [from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfn3djc76o3ptv5/BSM.zip?dl=0) and then give me some instructions on how I should go about compiling and using it. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that someone went rogue on the project file, because normally all paths are defined in a way that is relative to the project or solution, making them portable.

In order to fix this, I see two options, either set up the project files from scratch or keep on hacking on them until they compile. Whichever path you take, keep in mind that VS supports placeholders like `$(SolutionDir)` you can refer to when setting up paths. If that doesn't work, please try to extract a minimal example.

Also, make sure you have a version control system set up, so you can retrace your steps. This should be standard in any software development, but considering the state of the project I wouldn't be surprised to find other, hairy places there.

Comment: Thanks, but did you get a chance to download the solution and try to compile it?
I have corrected more than 100 paths as of now and still I am getting the exact 5 errors that I used to get before.

Comment: What do you mean by setting up the project files from scratch?

Comment: You can create an empty C++ project to which you add the existing source files etc.